# How can I add myself to apache group?

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, command-line-interface

I'm running my CentOS server on my Xserver and what happen is that when I want to upgrade my Wordpress escpecially for now to Wordpress 3.3.2 the problem is that I got

`Warning: copy(/wp-admin/includes/update-core.php) [function.copy]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /wp-admin/includes/class-wp-filesystem-direct.php on line 200`

And I understand that this is a permission problem.

Because the owner:group of my wordpress is under `apache`

So I wish to know how can I add myself to the same group of `apache` or even in the same group with root using command line? [Terminal]

MORE INFO:

I have password `root` to do any kind of command that require root password.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the following (if you're in sudoers list) or under root:

```
 sudo adduser <username> apache
```

If you're not familiar with sudo, here is a [short guide](http://www.wlug.org.nz/SudoHowto):

Comment: it said command not found?

Comment: If I have multiple users on my server with different websites, does adding the users to the apache group pose any security risk?

Answer (score 24):

for an existing user

```
sudo /usr/sbin/usermod -a -G apache <username>
```

Answer (score 13):

If the user exists already, use

```
sudo usermod -g <groupname> <user>
```

If it is a new user,

```
sudo useradd -g <groupname> <user>
```

Comment: use `-a -G` for secondary group. Otherwise it's the primary group

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of convenience,

check your groups:

```
groups
```

add yourself to apache group

```
sudo usermod -a -G apache $USER
```

verify

```
groups $USER
```

logout and login again

verify

```
groups
```

Done